# Amavis crashing for unknown reason

Tags: debian, amavis

Amavis is crashing for an unknown reason. Luckily, we have Monit installed and it restarts the service within a minute, but that's just a bandaid on the issue. We need to fix the real problem.

Right before crashing, the following log entries exist in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter...
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa amavis[23039]: (23039-01) (!)TempDir removal: tempdir is to be PRESERVED: /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20170222T170218-23039-CLjT8mUN
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa amavis[22755]: (22755-08) (!)TempDir removal: tempdir is to be PRESERVED: /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20170222T170035-22755-v7F3P0kr
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa amavis[21924]: (21924-20) (!)TempDir removal: tempdir is to be PRESERVED: /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20170222T165050-21924-Vi1AOnu5
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa amavis[22053]: (22053-14) (!)TempDir removal: tempdir is to be PRESERVED: /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20170222T165124-22053-V_dDmOmV
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/10025/smtpd[22719]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/10025/smtpd[22759]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/10025/smtpd[22718]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22710]: B07E111FD54: to=<user1@example.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=17, delays=0.23/14/0.31/2.3, dsn=4.3.2, status=deferred (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 421 4.3.2 Service shutting down, closing channel (in reply to end of DATA command))
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22710]: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22709]: B07E111FD54: to=<user2@example.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=17, delays=0.23/14/0.08/2.6, dsn=4.3.2, status=deferred (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 421 4.3.2 Service shutting down, closing channel (in reply to end of DATA command))
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22709]: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22708]: BFF1D11FD58: to=<user3@example.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=17, delays=0.23/15/0.03/2.2, dsn=4.3.2, status=deferred (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 421 4.3.2 Service shutting down, closing channel (in reply to end of DATA command))
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22708]: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22707]: 8CDCC11FCF4: to=<user4@example.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=17, delays=0.38/14/0.11/2.6, dsn=4.3.2, status=deferred (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 421 4.3.2 Service shutting down, closing channel (in reply to end of DATA command))
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22707]: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22710]: BFF1D11FD58: to=<user5@example.com>, relay=none, delay=17, delays=0.23/17/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22707]: 16B531207A6: to=<user6@example.com>, relay=none, delay=17, delays=0.42/17/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22710]: 16B531207A6: to=<user7@example.com>, relay=none, delay=17, delays=0.42/17/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22709]: E9CA411F8BA: to=<user8@example.com>, relay=none, delay=4.9, delays=0.53/4.4/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa postfix/smtp-amavis/smtp[22708]: E9CA411F8BA: to=<user9@example.com>, relay=none, delay=4.9, delays=0.53/4.4/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa amavis[23084]: Stopping amavisd: amavisd-new.
Feb 22 17:02:20 hoa systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter.
Feb 22 17:02:21 hoa systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter...
```

At this point, Monit kicks in and Amavis restarts.

I've done quite a bit of searching, but can't seem to find the issue. It's possible that the server is running low on memory, but there doesn't appear to be any errors logged about being unable to allocate memory. Therefore I'm not sure if that is truly the problem or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up with this question, I believe that the issue was indeed a shortage of memory. We doubled the memory for our server and the issue has yet to arise again. I'm surprised, however, that none of the log messages indicated that memory was the culprit.